# Kotlin, IntelliJ Idea, limitations in value of to Double

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, readline

is it possible in IntelliJ Idea to code restrictions in console? When I have simple line:

```
val height = readLine()?.toDouble()
```

I would like to limit the possible input format only to #.##, where "#" is a prime number.

Comment: No, it's not possible via the IDE configuration.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Are asking about how to validate input in Kotlin? Or are asking about limiting what you can type in the console of the IDE?

Comment: The second option. I asking about limiting what can I type in the console of the IDE. Can I  limit the possible input format only to #.##

Comment: Even if you develop a console plugin for IntelliJ which can limit the input format, your application will run and be used in numerous other consoles like 'iTerm2', 'gnome-terminal', 'power console' ... It would not be worth to try to control all these consoles. But validating the input format and requesting new input whenever the input wrong would be much more easier.

Comment: Yes I agree with you. I will probably do that. Thanks for your help!